# TYPO3 TypoScript: Language file with arguments

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

how can I render a locallang key with arguments in TypoScript? (replace the %s with a value)

```
<trans-unit id="author">
    <source>created by %s</source>
</trans-unit>
```

In Fluid it's done the following:

```
<f:translate key="author" arguments="{0:authorName}"/>
```

And now via TypoScript? I tried the following:

```
page.10 = TEXT    
page.10.dataWrap = {LLL:EXT:my_ext/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:author|'Me'}
```

=====
Solution 1 via UserFunc:

```
page.10 = USER_INT
page.10 {
    userFunc = FluidTranslate->main
    extensionName = my_ext
    key = tx_myext_domain_model_mymodel.author
    arguments.0 = Me
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
class FluidTranslate
{
  public function main($content, $conf)
  {
    $extensionName = $conf['extensionName'];
    $key = $conf['key'];
    $arguments = $conf['arguments.'];

    $value = \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\LocalizationUtility::translate($key, $extensionName, $arguments);
    return $value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible in the `TEXT` object yet, because for resolving the `LLL:` from TS the method `TypoScriptFrotnendController->sL()` is used.

You could however call a user function with the `USER` object and fetch your label there with `LocalizationUtility::translate()` where you can pass arguments.

Answer (score 4):

If your problem is only the %s part, then you could use stdwrap.replacement to process that:

```
  stdWrap.replacement {
    10 {
      search = %s
      replace = Me
    }
  }
```

See https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Replacement/Index.html

Answer (score 1):

Fluid templates support these markers (`sprintf()` style) because the TranslateViewHelper calls LocalizationUtility which calls `vsprintf()` on the resolved LLL.

However, this same processing is not available through TypoScript at the current time. Although it technically could be added as a new type of `stdWrap` function. Previously this feature has been suggested in a form that allowed calling any PHP function - but this was (reasonably so) rejected due to security concerns and the fact that TypoScript developers are second class citizens (compared to raw PHP) in TYPO3.

That being said there is ONE immediately available option that you could use to reproduce the behavior as an `stdWrap`:

There is a hook location at `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['tslib/class.tslib_content.php']['stdWrap']` which allows you to register a class name which implements `\TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\ContentObject\ContentObjectStdWrapHookInterface` that can trigger on special `stdWrap` configurations and perform your `sprintf()` or `vsprintf()` call on the LLL value after it is resolved.

On a side note, if you complete such a feature, it would make a lot of sense to suggest/contribute it back to TYPO3. It appears to me to be a reasonable feature request!

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm currently working with TYPO3 CMS 6.2.x the userFunc worked for me.
I extended the TypoScript cause I needed to react on dynamic values, based on CONTENT in combination with select.

TypoScript:

```
page.99 = CONTENT
page.99 {
  table = tt_content
  select {
    uidInList = 484
    pidInList = 156
  }
  selectFields = uid

  renderObj = COA
  renderObj {

    10 = USER
    10 {
        userFunc = FluidTranslate->main
        extensionName = my_ext
        key = tx_myext_domain_model_mymodelname.langkey
        fields.0 = uid
    }
  }
}
```

UserFunction:

```
<?php

class FluidTranslate
{

    /**
     * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\ContentObject\ContentObjectRenderer
     */
    public $cObj = null;

    public function main($content, $conf)
    {
        $extensionName = $conf['extensionName'];
        $key = $conf['key'];
        $arguments = array();
        $fields = $conf['fields.'];

        foreach ($fields as $field) {
            $arguments[] = $this->cObj->data[$field];
        }


        $value = \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\LocalizationUtility::translate($key, $extensionName, $arguments);
        return $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Either switch the COA_INT to COA or the USER_INT to USER or even remove the COA_INT and use the USER_INT directly to get a bit better performance and remove not needed lines

Answer (score 0):

One can use `FLUIDTEMPLATE` with inline template in order to use the ViewHelper:

```
page.10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
page.10 {
    template = TEXT
    template = {f:translate(key: 'author', arguments: {0: authorName}, extensionName: 'my_ext')}
    variables {
        authorName = TEXT
        authorName {
            field = author_name
        }
    }
}
```